# Шифрованая строка в php и java отличается

Tags: php, java

Шифрую одну и туже строку одним и тем же ключем в пхп и ява на выходе получается разная строка. Подскажите в чем у меня ошибка?

```
$textToEncrypt = $_GET['login'];
$secretHash = $_GET['key'];
$encryptionMethod = "AES";  
$iv = "1234567891234567";
$encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash,0, $iv );
$data = base64_encode ($iv.$encryptedMessage);
echo $data;


IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("1234567891234567".getBytes("UTF-8"));
  //генирируем случайный АЕС ключ
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            byte[] key = ("ytrewq").getBytes("UTF-8");
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
           SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv);
           byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes());
            String loadCriptLogin = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
System.out.println(loadCriptLogin);
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(loadCriptLogin);
```

Comment: Код не запускал, но попробую предположить, что строки `$textToEncrypt` и `s.getBytes()` имеют разные кодировки

Comment: Как минимум стоит задавать более точные характеристики шифра. AES это только вид шифра, а стоит явно указывать режим и padding. они могут быть разными по умолчанию у java и php

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` чтобы получить список доступных алгоритмов шифрования. Значение `$encryptionMethod` неверное.